# Jquery FullCalendar : How to show Events calendar for a range of days?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, plugins, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement a event schedule planner using [Adam Shaw's Jquery Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar).

I tried having various time slot intervals, various views, But I could not figure out how to display a list of few days in day view instead of just one day at a time.

> For instance I need to display for days 25th December to 5th January ,
>   the number of days could be >=1 ( even > 7 possible so not a week view
>   ).

It would be great if you could help me figure out if there is an option to display a range of dates in day view.

Comment: These are some standard views which are associated with a calender. I am afraid you will not be able to do this currently using arshaw.

Comment: if you can't find it in docs...would likely have to be custom coded to extend plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best you can do is to have for a specific day, showing in this day, a number of events that will simulate days from 25th December to 5thJanuary. For example, say you want to show in 26th December days from 25th Dec to 5th January:

```
events:[
  {
   'start':2013-12-26,
   'end':2013-12-26,
   allDay: true,
   'title': "Day 25th Dec 2013" 

  }
   ...
  {
   'start':2013-12-26,
   'end':2013-12-26,
   allDay: true,
   'title': "Day 5th January 2014"

  }
]
```

Now the title you could generate it dynamically meaning when you create your events the title could be set dynamically.

OR / ||

You can show in different time slots in one day he same thing but with half an our intervals.

```
events:[
  {
   'start':2013-12-26 07:00:00,
   'end':2013-12-26 07:30:00,
   allDay: false,
   'title': "Day 25th Dec 2013" 

  }
   ...
  {
   'start':2013-12-26 23:00:00,
   'end':2013-12-26 23:30:00,
   allDay: false,
   'title': "Day 5th January 2014"

  }
]
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess you are close, The First one appeals good, You mean I should apply the same one day view, for each of those day so that i get a list of one-day-calendar's rite ?.

Comment: Exactly, this is what you can do **Without** hacking the calendar :)

Comment: oh, k , Just now got a hang of it, I will maintain an array of events one for each day, and do it separately. :D